# Creating a page with a citation

Tags: formatting

I have started setting up the .tex for my thesis, and I would like to put a page with a citation I really like after the index and before the first chapter (introduction). Ideally, it would be a blank page with only the citation positioned probably in the middle, or in the upper right quarter of the page. I need something like a titlepage, but it's not for the title, but for a page somewhere inside the document instead.

What is the correct way do do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the facilities of the `epigraph` package.
For a single citation, you can use the `epigraph`  command. For several citations on the same page, use the `epigraphs` environment and the `\qitem{text}{source}` for each individual citation.

You also can have citations after a chapter header with the `epigraphhead` command.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.55\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{40ex}
\leavevmode
\epigraph{ In the midst of the word he was trying to say,\\
          In the midst of his laughter and glee,\\
     He had softly and suddenly vanished away---\\
          For the Snark was a Boojum, you see.}{\em Lewis Carroll}
\clearpage
%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following might give you a good starting point:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for easy creation of text
\title{Smart Title}
\author{Smart Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%% in the middle of the page:
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill
\begin{center}
    I have three kids and no money!\\
    Why can't I have no kids and three money?
\end{center}
\hfill\emph{-- Homer J. Simpson}
\vfill
\clearpage
%%
%% at the upper right quarter:
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%
\begin{center}
    I have three kids and no money!\\
    Why can't I have no kids and three money?
\end{center}
\hfill\emph{-- Homer J. Simpson}
}
\clearpage
%%
\blindtext% begin of document
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without loading any packages properbly the easiest way is a vspace/vfill combination

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
Habet enim praeteriti doloris secura recordatio delectationem
\vskip1em
\hfill\emph{Cicero}
\vfill
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this any different from the answer I posted (except the usage of `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `~\vfill`)?

Comment: \vfill can't be used at the top of the page so the tilde is just an empty spacer. \vspace*{\fill} can be used atop of a page.

Comment: And what are the significant differences? Do you think the result of `\vspace*{\fill}` and `~\vfill` differ much?